# Could not find a declaration file for module 'tailwind-scrollbar'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use some tailwind packages for a Next.js application and I'm encountering an issue that I can't find a fix for. When I add a "require" to my tailwind.config.js file, I keep getting this error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'tailwind-scrollbar'. 
'/Users/beatsbyrsd/Documents/JavaScript/React/instagram-clone/node_modules/.pnpm/tailwind-scrollbar@1.3.1/node_modules/tailwind-scrollbar/src/index.js' 
implicitly has an 'any' type. 
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/tailwind-scrollbar` if it exists or add a 
new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'tailwind-scrollbar';
```

Here's what my tailwind.config.js file looks like:

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
        "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [
        require("@tailwindcss/forms"),
        require("tailwind-scrollbar"),
        require("tailwind-scrollbar-hide"),
    ],
};
```

I've looked around online and found methods like creating a `global.d.ts` file and declare the module, trying `npm i --save-dev @types/tailwind-scrollbar`, but nothing seems to be working.
I appreciate the help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please do this...

```
npm uninstall  tailwind-scrollbar
```

Remove from config

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
        "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [
        require("@tailwindcss/forms"),

    ],
};
```

Then

```
 npm i  tailwind-scrollbar-hide
```

add to config

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
        "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
        "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [
        require("@tailwindcss/forms"),
        require("tailwind-scrollbar-hide"),
    ],
};
```

use this class for hide scrollbar

```
scrollbar-hide
```